# Power BI workspace limits

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

How many reports can I create in one power bi workspace ?

How many datasources can I create over there ?

**Details**:

We are going to implement our own application and use Power BI Embedded features. Our app will own all data, thus our users will be working with reports on behalf of one master Power BI Pro account. Since every user could have multiple reports the question is how many reports can I store into one workspace ? I found some links where developers claim, that only 200 reports can be saved into one workspace, but I've not found any official doc on this. Currently we created one report in workspace and cloned it via saveAs function of Power BI JS SDK. So far I could create more than 1000 reports. So what limits are ?

**UPDATE1**

So far I reached limit in 1005 reports in one workspace. I can not create new one 1006s report neither from Power BI Services nor API call.  Just got error "Unable to save the report" with some technical details. Once I removed one report I can create new one, but again can't exceed limit in 1005 reports.

**UPDATE2**

So when I save report (in Power BI Services )  got standard message box with error and link to  "technical details", when click on it I set of ids:
[image: error]
Using embedded JS SDK got similar thing:

```
function GetCurrentReport() {

    var embedContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];
    return powerbi.get(embedContainer);
}
const report = GetCurrentReport();
report.saveAs({name:"NewReportName1111"});
```

[image: powerbiembedded]

In both cases 500 error came from some APIs.

**UPDATE3**

It looks I reach limit, Fidler says:
[image: error]

some API throws `ResourceLimitsReportCountExceeded` exception. 
Do someone have any ideas how to increase this `CountPermitted` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I contacted Microsoft representative and asked all those questions and more.

There are questions and answers this person got, I believe, from Power BI product team:

1. What is max count of reports per workspace ?

ANSWER: **You have a limit of 1000 datasets per WS, or 1000 reports per dataset. You have probably reached one of them.**

---

2. What is max count of workspaces per one PRO user ?

ANSWER: **Right now it is 250, will be increased to 1000 with the new workspace experience that is now in public preview**

---

3. Is it possible to extend that limit of reports in workspace to some bigger number ?

ANSWER: **Not right now**

---

4. If using dedicated capacity Power BI Embedded App Services , can we manage such limits ?

ANSWER: **These limits are not related to using capacity. You must purchase a dedicated capacity to go to production with PBI Embedded.**

---

5. What version of Power BI API should we use ? Version 1 or Version 2 ?

ANSWER: **There is only 1 API version- V1. The ‘V2’ you see is for the SDK of PBI API**

Comment: These limits are now stated in the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-multi-tenancy#deployment-considerations-and-limitations

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Power BI provides work-space to create or publish report from power BI desktop. Below are details of data-set and report capacity in Power BI service for free or Pro users.

1. Free users have a maximum 1 GB data capacity.
2. Pro users of Power BI Pro have 10 GB maximum capacity.
3. Pro users can create groups, with a maximum 10 GB data capacity each.

There is no limitation on number of reports but the total size of all the reports should not exceed 1 GB for free user and 10 GB for Pro user. Also, Pro user can create 10 GB work-space for each user.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a PowerBI pro account, each workspace has a 10GB storage limit. If you want to upgrade to premium, the storage space depends on the plan you choose. For more details see this : [Storage in PowerBI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way. I was able create 1005 reports, but now when I try to save as new one I got error. I can't add one more report. At the same time into storage I has indication that "47 Mb of 10 GB used", thus it's far from run out. At link you provided I found info about datasets and no word about max reports count. As I understand Power BI is not intended to use huge   amount of reports in one workspace, but as ISV I have such app that allows user have multiple reports and it can reach thousands.

Comment: Can you post an image of the "technical error" you are getting while uploading the new report.

Comment: How many datasets are there in your reports? The workspace allows only maximum of 200 datasets to be published with in it. This limit of 200 includes the combination of datasets and reports together. But, there are some workarounds. Please refer this link : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2018/02/26/you-cannot-publish-more-than-200-datasetreport-together-within-an-workspace-in-power-bi-service/

Comment: It looks they increased limits. See my answers.